# What is .info referring to in pseudocode

Tags: pseudocode

I am reading pseudo code for a fundamental linked list and some of the methods have ____.info in them. Here is an example:

```
Algorithm: ToArray() //Returns an array of items from the list
START
Let Current be a node;
Lat ItemArray be an array of items in the list;
Let X be an integer, initialized to 0; //assume array sub-scripting begins at 0
Current = First;
While(Current <> NULL)
     Increment x by 1;
     ItemArray[x-1] = Current.Info; 
     Current = Current.Next;
End-While;
Return ItemArray;
STOP
```

What does the .Info do/mean?

Comment: This doesn't look like Java to me.

Comment: @trooper He explains it's pseudocode in the first sentence.

Comment: Its pseudo code, so its some member variable or method on the object stored in Current.

Comment: Now don't get excited :P It was mistagged, and has been corrected.

Answer (score 6):

`Current` in your pseudo code seems to be an element of the list. That basically holds the pointer to the `Next` element and also the actual data at that position. It seems `Info` is a bad name for exactly that: the actual data at the position in the list represented by `Current`.

Comment: Ohhh okay! Thank you!

Wasn't sure if .info was specific to java.